# JQuery selector, partial DOM searching for performances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I'm actually working with Jquery and at some point I use Jquery selectors to make my page work. The issue here is that the HTML I work with can get very long depending on the data I work with and it looks like this.

### HTML

```
<div class="mailing"></div>
    <input type="text" class="mail_subject"/>
    <input type="text" class="mail_body"/> <!-- I can have 1 to n number of these -->

    <!-- Preview tags -->
    <p class='main_subject'></p>
    <p class='main_body'></p>

    <!-- 
        And a few more things we don't use here 
    -->
</div>

<div id="table1">
    <table id="ranking">
        <tbody>
            <!-- Data, can have 0 to ~3500 rows -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, my page is more or less divided in two parts, the `<div class="mailing">`, which contains a few forms, and the `<div id="table1">` that is about displaying lots of data.

In my mailing div I have a few inputs and an auto-updated preview that takes the data from the inputs. What I have here is a kind of "mail builder" with the preview giving me the result with html formatting.

The problem here is about performance, my JQuery is slowed by the table and I got lag when I type in a form and I don't want it to search the whole document as I already know my data will be in the mailing div.

### JS

```
$('.mailing').on('change click keyup keydown', function () {
    // Here I append the mail_subject input to the preview
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('.main_subject').text($('.subject_select').val());

    // Here I append each mail_body input to the preview
    $('.bodies_select').each(function () {
        text = $(this).val();
        /*
         * Some computation for the text
         */
        jQuery('<span/>', {text: text}).appendTo('.main_body');
    });
});
```

I have a few more functions like theses and a few more computation, but I think we got the idea of what my code looks like.

My question is, is there a way, when I use JQuery selectors like `$('.main_subject')` or `$('.bodies_select')` to not search the whole DOM document but only in my `mailing` div for example? The problem is that I can store my elements in variable since it as multiple occasion to be updated.

Comment: way too many events!!! Why would you need keyup and keydown together? Both will trigger the same dom search. Also should throttle those if you need real time updates and not just wait for change to occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use context with jQuery to improve performances :

`$('.bodies_select', '.mailing')`

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

You can even optimize the selectors with some technics :

> https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

Comment: This is minimal optimization compared to caching the collection to avoid a dom search each time

Comment: of course it it necessary to store in a variable for reusing

Comment: not really an *"of course"* when it's not stated though...and lots of people don't recognize this issue

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to place the parent elemenent before

```
$('.mailing .main_subject')
```

You should probably read a bit about selectors
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/